# Restrict special user and host of ftp in the Linux Instance

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, amazon-ec2, aws

I am using `WinSCP` for connecting ftp to Linux Instance and I want to restrict special user and host.

I install `plesk` on my Linux Ec2 instance and I thought it is using `proftpd` for ftp service and `xinetd` for service name.

So I config `/etc/proftpd.conf` and `sudo service xinetd restart`, but It was not working.

So I decided to change the `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` and config like this

/etc/hosts.allow:

```
sshd: 1.2.3.4
```

/etc/hosts.deny:

```
sshd: ALL
```

It's working. But I want to restrict special user and host means one IP address can access with only one username.

So I tried

```
sshd: username@ipaddress
```

But I was not working.

My final goal is to one user can access with one IP address to one folder.

Answer (score 2):

The line `sshd: username@ipaddress` in `/etc/hosts.allow` would apply the restriction to the `sshd` service (and only if it was compiled with `libwrap` support or configured to use TCP wrappers). It does nothing at all to `proftpd`.

If you are using the `scp` or `SFTP` mode of WinSCP to connect, you are effectively using the `sshd` service, and the `proftpd` will not be involved at all. If you are using a `FTP` or `FTPS` mode, then `proftpd` could handle those, and `sshd` will not be involved at all.

(Running an unnecessary service with a poorly-understood configuration on an internet-accessible server is begging to be infected by malware. For the sake of yourself and the other users of EC2, please don't do that.)

Using the `sshd: username@ipaddress` form in `/etc/hosts.allow` requires that *the client* must be running `identd` or equivalent service. `identd` is a service that reveals the local username associated with an active TCP connection to anyone who asks. In modern times, this is deemed a dangerous and unnecessary information disclosure, and so the `identd` service is no longer enabled nor usually even installed by default on modern systems.

And if the client is not a Unix-like system maintained by someone you trust, the remote `identd` service might be configured to tell lies even if it exists and is not blocked by firewalls. To sum up, adding usernames to `/etc/hosts.allow` is not likely to be useful in a modern network environment.

You'll need to first accept incoming connections from every authorized client host, and then once they disclose the username they want to connect as (as part of the authentication procedure), you can reject the non-matching combinations.

With `sshd`, you could do it by adding something like this to your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file:

```
AllowUsers user1@ip.address.1 user2@ip.address.2 ...
```

Note that this will also restrict regular SSH connections, so make sure you don't lock yourself out.